# How do I implement a mutex lock using TestAndSet (with busy waiting)?

Tags: multithreading, operating-system

I am trying to implement the following functions: lock(m) and unlock(m), where m is a boolean variable (the mutex lock).

So far I have the implementation for TestAndSet:

```
function TestAndSet(boolean_ref lock) {
  boolean initial = lock;
  lock = true;
  return initial;
}
```

I am looking for a pseudocode solution. How do I consequently implement lock and unlock given my TestAndSet method ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are okay with busy waiting, the code for lock/unlock could be:

```
lock(lock m): 
  while (test_and_set(m))
    ;


unlock(lock m):
  m = false;
```

You can find more on this topic [here](https://people.csail.mit.edu/rinard/osnotes/h5.html).